# StreamBuilder taking too long to update (or not updating at all)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-streambuilder

I use firebase authentication in my app and I have a widget called `AuthGate` that the app launches as its home. In `AuthGate` there is just a `StreamBuilder` that listens to `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` and returns different screens depending on the user state. When no user is logged in, the `LoginScreen` is returned, and when they log in through one of the methods, the `StreamBuilder` should send them to the `HomeScreen`. The same should happen when registering and when they sign out it should automatically send them back to the `LoginScreen`. My issue is that sometimes the changes are not detected at all, and even when they are, it takes at least a few seconds. Is there a way to make it update faster? I like this method a lot more than the way I used to do it (pushing replacements), because it's cleaner and more efficient, so I hope there is a solution. Here is the code in the `AuthGate`:

```
class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const LoginScreen();
          } else if (snapshot.data?.displayName == null ||
              snapshot.data?.email == null ||
              snapshot.data?.photoURL == null) {
            return UpdateProfileScreen(user: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return HomeScreen(user: snapshot.data!);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: "sometimes the changes are not detected at all" That seems unlikely. Are you sure that in those cases the persisted credentials aren't getting rejected by the auth server?

Comment: I did figure out that when it wasn't updating at all, it was likely because the application lost connection to Xcode and was freezing. However, I am still looking for solutions to the part about updating taking too long.